# flags enum property where clause not affect on sql query in entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, .net-core

For assign mutiple type to user, I use UserType enum that decorate with Flags attribute as fallow:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserType
{
    Default = 0,
    Moderator = 1,
    Doctor = 2,
    Administrator = 4,
}
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public bool Suspended { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

And assign userType to user,

```
user.UserType = UserType.Moderator | UserType.Administrator;
```

when below query runs,

```
var t = dbContext.Users.Where(e => e.UserType.HasFlag(UserType.Doctor)).ToList();
```

This sql query generate, as can be seen there is no trace of where expression in query. However, ef query result is ok, but the problem is that all User load to memroy and no filter occur in database, indeed query occur in memory

```
SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[PasswordHash], [e].[PhoneNumber], [e].[PhoneNumberConfirmed]
, [e].[SecurityStamp], [e].[Suspended], [e].[TwoFactorEnabled],[e].[UserName], [e].[UserType]
FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [e]
```

this problem not exists in ef 6.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been raised previously in [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2852) , and added this to the Backlog milestone on Aug 19, 2015و But now is not supported